# SQL Count across columns based on an ID

Tags: sql, group-by, count

I'm trying to do a sql query which returns only the records that fulfill the following criteria:
It should return the records in which the value "a" appears twice or more across all columns of the table.

I have a table like the one below

table:

| ID | P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | a | b | b |
| 2 | a | b | b | b |
| 3 | a | b | a | b |
| 4 | b | b | b | b |

Desired output:

| ID | P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | a | b | b |
| 3 | a | b | a | b |

So far I manage to return the records in which "a" appears across any column like this

```
Select \*
from table
where a in (P1,P2,P3,P4)
```

But I need to drop the values in which "a" appears only once. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you using for your database, SQL-Server, MySQL, etc.?

Comment: Hi! I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNPIVOT` and count rows per ID.
This works in `sql-server`.  Your mileage may vary.  Maybe tag your question with the database system (RDBMS) name next time.
It will also be difficult if you don't know how many columns you have, but your question doesn't specifically say that.

```
create table #table (
ID int,
P1 varchar(5),
P2 varchar(5),
P3 varchar(5),
P4 varchar(5)
)

insert #table
values 
  (1, 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b')
, (2, 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b')
, (3, 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b')
, (4, 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b')
;

with unpvt as (
select ID, p, val
from (select ID, P1, P2, P3, P4 from #table) p
unpivot (val for p in (P1, P2, P3, P4)) as unpvt
),
cnt as (
select ID
--, count(distinct p) as cnt
from unpvt
where val = 'a'
group by id
having count(distinct p) > 1
)

select t.*
from #table t
  inner join cnt c on c.ID = t.ID

drop table #table
```